# Different class if different sidebars are active on WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Im having hard times to figure out how to do it.

I build theme for wordpress, and theme is based on bootstrap.And i need to have different fow classes if different sidebars are active.

For example, I have 4 sidebars on footer.

```
footer1-sidebar
footer2-sidebar
footer3-sidebar
footer4-sidebar
```

so if only 1 sidebar is active of these 4, not matter which one i should have

```
<div class="row col-lg-12">
    footer1-sidebar
</div>
```

But if 2 sidebars are active i need somehow to divide it like

```
<div class="row col-lg-6">
    footer2-sidebar
</div>
<div class="row col-lg-6">
    footer4-sidebar
</div>
```

and so on...

So no matter which one is activated 1 and 3, or 2 and 4 or 1,2 and 4, or all 4 are active. I need to somehow count them and divide rows to number of sidebars in line.

### EDIT

Here's the code of footer-sidebar.php that i have currently on my theme.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer1-sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'footer2-sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'footer3-sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'footer4-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
<div class="footer-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('footer1-sidebar') ) : ?>
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer1-sidebar'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('footer2-sidebar') ) : ?>
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer2-sidebar'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('footer3-sidebar') ) : ?>
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer3-sidebar'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('footer4-sidebar') ) : ?>
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer4-sidebar'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

With this now the problem is that if one or 2 sidebars are not active(don't have widgets) it leaves empty space on that column.

Comment: How do you determine whether they're active at all? And, presumably, you want to do this on the server (with [tag:php]) rather on the client (with [tag:javascript])?

Comment: Well there's option on wordpress is_active_sidebar that checks if sidebar have widgets, and of course i want to do this on the server. im currently looking at some options if i can make it count all the active sidebars in footer.php page and styles need to render before. not with javascript.

Comment: Do you've got 4 sidebars or 4 widgets? And how do you determine which sidebar/widget is on and off on a page?

Comment: i have 4 sidebars, and i updated question with the code i have on my footer page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with kind of a counter which add +1 on every active sidebar, and finally divide 12 rows to number of counted sidebars

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer1-sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'footer2- sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'footer3-sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'footer4-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
<?php $count = 0;
if ( is_active_sidebar('footer1-sidebar') ) : $count++; endif; 
if ( is_active_sidebar('footer2-sidebar') ) : $count++; endif; 
if ( is_active_sidebar('footer3-sidebar') ) : $count++; endif; 
if ( is_active_sidebar('footer4-sidebar') ) : $count++; endif;
$row = 'col-lg-'. 12/$count .' col-md-'. 12/$count .' col-sm-'. 12/$count;
?>
<div class="footer-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('footer1-sidebar') ) : ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $row ?>">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer1-sidebar'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('footer2-sidebar') ) : ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $row ?>">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer2-sidebar'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('footer3-sidebar') ) : ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $row ?>">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer3-sidebar'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('footer4-sidebar') ) : ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $row ?>">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer4-sidebar'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</div>
```